# IndexError: list index out of range python (flask)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making python app and I wanted to know why my program display IndexError: list index out of range. I wanted to create flask app which displays data from database.

Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def displaytask():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks")
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    empty_table=false
    if data[0][0]==0:
          empty_table=true
    return render_template('index.html', data=data, value=empty_table)
```

It displays data only if they are already inserted if database is empty then error message show.

Error message:      `if data[0][0]==0: IndexError: list index out of range`

I wanted to display data in jinja blocks:

```
   {% for row in data %}
        {% if value == true %}
           <li><span class='text'>No Record Found.</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        <li><span class="text">{{ row[1] }}</span>
         <i id="removeBtn" class="icon fa fa-trash"></i>
        </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `data[0][0]` doesn't exist. So either `data[0]` doesn't have anything in it that can be indexed into, or `data` doesn't have anything in it. Have you checked `data` to see if it looks like what you expect it to look like?

Comment: The result from fetchall is a list of tuples. Result should contain one tuple, which would contain one number, which is the row count. I already check data and data[0] it's the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just wanted check the data is null of not, just passing the data variable to template, and check with jinja. So the jinja template like this:

```
{% if data %}
{% for row in data %}
<li>
    <span class="text">{{ row[1] }}</span>
    <i id="removeBtn" class="icon fa fa-trash"></i>
</li>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<li><span class='text'>No Record Found.</span></li>
{% endif %}
```

more for tests in : https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates.html#list-of-builtin-tests

Answer (score 2):

If there is no data in the DB then `data` will be and empty list.
If you then try to access it `data[0][0]` then you will get an out of range error as there isnt a position 0 in an empty list

```
In [420]: r = []
In [421]: r[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-421-8418cdc095ae> in <module>
----> 1 r[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

You will need to check if data is empty before trying to access it.